# E0070 incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I use Visual studio 2019 community , ue4 project from source.
I use html5 already tested ungine build thats is ok.

I Survival project i have error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type is not allowed  SurvivalGame    F:\APPS\rocket-craft\rocket-craft\versions\4.24-Survival\EpicSurvivalGameSeries-4.24\SurvivalGame\Source\SurvivalGame   F:\APPS\rocket-craft\rocket-craft\versions\4.24-Survival\EpicSurvivalGameSeries-4.24\SurvivalGame\Source\SurvivalGame\STypes.h  87
```

Code Line:

```cpp
//                                                                     error mark
PointDamageEvent.DamageTypeClass = DamageTypeClass ? DamageTypeClass : UDamageType::StaticClass();
```

Original error goes from emscripten build but any way even in visual studio when i open critical file i see same error log.

I am not c++ skilled programmer !
How to avoid this any suggestion ...

All other code looks like :

This is random line from project

```cpp
void ASBaseCharacter::FellOutOfWorld(const class UDamageType& DmgType)

/* Fallback to default DamageType if none is specified */
UDamageType const* const DamageType = DamageEvent.DamageTypeClass ? DamageEvent.DamageTypeClass->GetDefaultObject<UDamageType>() : GetDefault<UDamageType>();

Die(Health, FDamageEvent(UDamageType::StaticClass()), Killer, nullptr);

UCLASS()
class SURVIVALGAME_API USDamageType : public UDamageType

TSubclassOf<UDamageType> PunchDamageType;

etc...
```

Comment: That error usually means you are forward declaring a class/struct, but never including the actual source file for it. Is the header for `DamageTypeClass` included?

Comment: Its is ue4 i am not sure , i am sure that `#include <utility>` is not solution (from stackoverflow) ...

Comment: It's complaining about the `SurvivalGame` class. Check to see if you have any forward declarations there. These are statements like `class Something;` or `struct SomethingElse;`, usually in your header file. Make sure all of these things are then `#include`d in your cpp

Comment: Yes it was simple fix i just look similar situation intro other files and build now works !